# Printing ascii characters that move across screen in emu8086 & removing characters

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Fairly new to assembly and emu8086 and I'm trying to get an ASCII character (an asterisk*) to move across the screen in different directions starting from a certain point.

I can get the asterisk to go right (see code snippet), but how would I make it go left? Up, down?

```
    mov ah,downCol    ; set cursor position
    mov bh,downRow
    mov dl, downCol   ; change column 
    mov dh, downRow  ; change row  

    mov cx, 20 

    loop1:       
        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, 2ah ;*  
        int 21h 

        ;mov dl, 20h ;space
        ;int 21h 
        ;mov dl, 08h
        ;int 21h

        loop loop1
```

Also, I've been looking at trying to remove the * shortly after it's outputted so it looks like it's moving, but as you can see from the commented section, it's not working. What should I be doing?

Comment: You are mixing DOS-interrupts(21h) with BIOS-interrupts(10h). In your case you are passing the output of a DOS-interrupt as an input to a BIOS-interrupt. I really don't know what that will result in...

Comment: 1: What keys do you plan on using to determine direction? 2: What sort of timing mechanism to regulate how fast asterisk moves? 3: What is going to happen when char reaches edges of screen? 4: How are you going to start and stop movement? 5: How are you going to determine starting point? To place characters the simplest way, I'd write directly to video or use BIOS functions. See SetCursorPostion & GetCurorPositon in Phoenix manual.

Comment: with standard VGA text mode it is probably easier just to write directly into video RAM (text mode memory starts at `B800:0000` at default, unless you change it): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode#Access_methods (also it's much faster than BIOS, which will backfire in your case, as you will have trouble to make the movement slow enough :D ... but single asterisk will be too fast even with BIOS calls).

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I've been looking at trying to remove the * shortly after it's outputted so it looks like it's moving, but as you can see from the commented section, it's not working.
>
> ```
> ;mov dl, 20h ;space
> ;int 21h 
> ;mov dl, 08h
> ;int 21h
> ```

This was close to success if you had first output the backspace (8) then followed by the space (32).

```
mov dl, 08h
int 21h
mov dl, 20h ;space
int 21h
```

---

> I'm trying to get an ASCII character (an asterisk*) to move across the screen in different directions starting from a certain point.

A program that does those things follows these steps:

- Position the cursor
- Draw an asterisk
- Wait a bit
- Remove the asterisk by drawing a space
- Modify the column or row (or both!)
- Repeat from the top

This example moves back an forth from the left to the right:

```
Top:
 mov  dh, Row
 mov  dl, Column
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  ah, 02h    ;SetCursor
 int  10h

 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, "*"
 mov  ah, 0Ah    ;DrawCharacter
 int  10h

 mov  dx, 0      ;Approximately 1/8 second
 mov  cx, 2
 mov  ah, 86h    ;Delay
 int  15h

 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, " "
 mov  ah, 0Ah    ;DrawCharacter
 int  10h

 mov  al, Sense  ;Is +1 to go right, is -1 to go left
 test al, al
 js   GoLeft
GoRight:
 inc  Column
 cmp  Column, 80
 jb   Top
 mov  Column, 78
 neg  Sense
 jmp  Top
GoLeft:
 dec  Column
 jns  Top
 mov  Column, 1
 neg  Sense
 jmp  Top

Column db 20
Row    db 12
Sense  db -1
```

This should give you an idea on how to solve the problem.

- Perhaps you could introduce 2 direction variables *SenseX* and *SenseY*?
- Perhaps you can let the user decide what the direction should be?
- ...